# SFMC Filtered Data Extension drops leading zero on text field

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a column of "text" data type in a DE. Some of the values have a leading zero. Ex: "0123456789"
When creating a filtered DE from this DE, the leading zeros all dropped. Why? How? This is a text filed so I dont understand how this happened or how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you filtering on a primary key or a non-nullable field? I've tested this and was able to keep the leading zero in the value:

**Source Data Extension:**

[image: Source DE]

**Filter:**

[image: Filter]

**Filtered Data Extension:**

[image: Test Leading Zero Result]

Comment: Ironically, what I suggested to my team member who had this problem was to run the filter again and see if we can replicate the behavior - the zeros were not dropped this time.  The field with the 0s is the primary key, however the filter was not on this field.